# Codeigniter : Updating multiple cart items

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am working with Codeigniter shopping cart. I want to update multiple cart items. this is what i'm doing

```
public function updatecart(){

    foreach ($this->input->post() as $value){
        $this->cart->update(array(
            'rowid'      =>     $value['rowid'],
            'qty'        =>     $value['qty'],
        ));
    }
    redirect(base_url().'product/cart');
}
```

This code updates only first item in cart instead of updating all the items , need your help to fix it, if I do  `print_r($this->input->post());` this is what I get .

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => ad61ab143223efbc24c7d2583be69251
            [qty] => 7
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [rowid] => d09bf41544a3365a46c9077ebb5e35c3
            [qty] => 1
        )

)
```

and when i update it only updates qty index for first array index

Comment: did you returning anything from update function in model ?

Comment: everything i had i pasted here, This is in my controller

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created the array pass it to this.

```
foreach ($this->input->post() as $value){
   $data[] = array(
      'rowid'      =>     $value['rowid'],
      'qty'        =>     $value['qty'],
    );
 }

$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'rowid');
```

This should update each row that has the rowid in the array, it is alot quicker as well

Comment: data is not in database ,

Comment: What do you mean it is not in database, it did not update?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
 public function updatecart(){
       $roids=$this->input->post('rowid');
      $gty=$this->input->post('qty');
if (!empty($roids)) {
   foreach($roids as $index=> $val ) {
      $data = array(
              'rowid' => $val ,
               'qty'    => $gty[$index]
            );
       $this->cart->update($data);
     }
}
}
```